# Converting a One Column to Character

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to convert only one column to a character using the mutate function and as.character.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? The column name is Origin and this is my code:

```
vehicles <- read_csv("vehicles.csv")

vehicles %>%
  mutate_at("Origin", as.character)
View(vehicles)
```

It should show this:

```
## Parsed with column specification:
## cols(
##   MPG = col_double(),
##   Cylinders = col_double(),
##   Engine_Size = col_double(),
##   Horse_Power = col_double(),
##   Vweight = col_double(),
##   Acceleration = col_double(),
##   Origin = col_character()
## )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to use `mutate_at` is to pass the variable names via `vars()` like

```
vehicles %>% mutate_at(vars(Origin), as.character)
```

In the newer versions of dplyr you can/should also use `across()`:

```
vehicles %>% mutate(across(Origin, as.character))
```